# in R: Column multiplication of a matrix with another matrix without a loop

Tags: r, matrix

I am using R v 3.2.3.

I am trying to solve a problem in a more elegant way.

I have written a simplified form of the problem below:

First Array: 10 vectors put into one matrix over time dimension 5

```
Array1 <- array(100,c(10,10,5))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [2,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [3,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [4,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [5,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [6,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [7,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [8,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [9,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
[10,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100

, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [2,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [3,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [4,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [5,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [6,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [7,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [8,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [9,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
[10,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100

                                                           .etc
```

Second Array: A 10 by 10 matrix for multiplication

```
Array2 = diag(0.5,10,10)
```

Adding a diagonal and diagonal-1 vector into the Second Array to Test

```
Array2[row(Array2)-1 == col(Array2)] = matrix(1-0.5,ncol(Array2)-1,1)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [2,]  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [3,]  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0   0.0
 [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5   0.0
[10,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5   0.5
```

I would like the columns of Array1 to be individually multiplied with Array 2.

The output of each multiplication would equals the value at time dimension 2 of Array 1...and so on up to 5. It is essentially overwriting the column at the third dimension.

I am doing this by using a loop of i+1 = i where i+1 would equal at time 2:

```
as.matrix(Array2)%*%as.matrix(Array1[,1:10,i])

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50    50
 [2,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [3,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [4,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [5,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [6,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [7,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [8,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [9,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
[10,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
```

Would this be an opportunity for lapply? Any advice is very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply`, which is specifically for margins of an array or matrix.

```
> a = apply(Array1, 3, function(x,y)as.matrix(y)%*%as.matrix(x), Array2)
> a
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]   50   50   50   50   50
  [2,]  100  100  100  100  100
  [3,]  100  100  100  100  100
  [4,]  100  100  100  100  100
  [5,]  100  100  100  100  100
  [6,]  100  100  100  100  100
  [7,]  100  100  100  100  100
  [8,]  100  100  100  100  100
  [9,]  100  100  100  100  100
 [10,]  100  100  100  100  100
 [11,]   50   50   50   50   50
 [12,]  100  100  100  100  100
 [13,]  100  100  100  100  100
...
[100,]  100  100  100  100  100
```

Then transform it back to array

```
> array(a, dim=c(10,10,5))
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50    50
 [2,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [3,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [4,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [5,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [6,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [7,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [8,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [9,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
[10,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100

, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50   50    50
 [2,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [3,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [4,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [5,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [6,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [7,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [8,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
 [9,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
[10,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
sapply(1:5, FUN=function(i) Array2 %*% Array1[,,i], simplify="array")
```

It is more readable than a `for` loop and may be a bit faster.